# Scala - Supplying Different Dependencies to Child Classes Instantiated by Factory

Tags: scala, factory, implicit

I am trying to write a job execution module that uses a factory to supply logic for executing a job, depending on the type of the job.

The quandry I have is how to supply *different* dependencies to the specific implementations, while keeping a generic signature for instantiation.

Abridged code follows.

Base class with factory:

```
abstract class JobExecution(job: Job, jobService: JobService) {
    def execute: Unit
}

object JobExecution {
  val registry: Map[Long, (Job, JobService) => JobExecution] = Map(
    1L -> ((j: Job, s: JobService) =>
      new SomeJobExecImpl(j, s).asInstanceOf[JobExecution])
  )

  def apply(job: Job, service: JobService): JobExecution = registry(job.jobTypeId)(job, service)
}
```

An incoming job is executed thusly:

```
// Note that here I have the services in scope that I would like to supply to the job execution implementation.

JobExecution(someJob, jobService).execute
```

I need to have an implementation something like this:

```
class SomeJobExecImpl(job: Job, jobService: JobService, otherService: OtherService)
  extends JobExecution(job, jobService) {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}
```

Or maybe:

```
class SomeJobExecImpl(job: Job, jobService: JobService)
                     (implicit otherService: OtherService)
  extends JobExecution(job, jobService) {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}
```

I have not been able to contrive a solution beyond some smelly work-arounds.

Is there cogent way I can do this while preserving the basic pattern, or does it require a wholesale change?

Note that I am not using a DI library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal change to your existing structure, one option is to list out all your services in a `ServiceRegistry` like:

```
trait ServiceRegistry {
  implicit val jobService: JobService
  implicit val otherService: OtherService
  ...
}
```

Then change your `JobExecution` registry:

```
...
object JobExecution {
  val registry: Map[Long, (Job, ServiceRegistry) => JobExecution] = Map(
    1L -> ((j: Job, r: ServiceRegistry) =>
      import r._
      new SomeJobExecImpl(j, r.jobService).asInstanceOf[JobExecution])
  )

  def apply(job: Job, serviceReg: ServiceRegistry): JobExecution = 
    registry(job.jobTypeId)(job, serviceReg)
}
```

And when an `JobExecution` implementation requires additional services:

```
class SomeJobExecImpl(job: Job, jobService: JobService)
                     (implicit otherService: OtherService)
  extends JobExecution(job, jobService) {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}
```

Comment: This bears some resemblance to one of the options I already contrived - having a single container for the service dependencies. I will see if I can work with it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This turns out to work well. The job execution caller implements the trait without any code changes, so it is as simple as passing "this" to the factory method.